# MySQL reclaim index space after large delete?

Tags: mysql, sql

After performing a large delete in MySQL, I understand you need to run a NULL ALTER to reclaim *disk* space, is this also true for reclaiming index space?

We have tables using > 10G of index space and have deleted/archived large chunks of this data and unsure if we need to rebuild the table in order to decrease the size of the *index*.

Can anyone offer any advice?

We are trying to avoid rebuilding the table since it would take quite awhile and lock the table.

Thanks!

Comment: What storage engine are you using?

Comment: InnoDB, MySQL 5.1

Comment: You don't "need" to... unless you "need" the space.  It will eventually be reused.

Answer (score 3):

You're using InnoDB. Unfortunately, in its default configuration, InnoDB never gives back disk space unless you are using `innodb_file_per_table`, in which case disk space can be re-claimed by running `optimize table foo`.

If you are not using `innodb_file_per_table`, then you need to do the following:

1. Use `mysqldump` to dump your databases to a file.
2. Drop your databases.
3. Stop mysql.
4. Delete your innodb files (or move them elsewhere).
5. Start up mysql.
6. Re-create your databases and re-import from the mysqldump file.

Needless to say, you had better make sure you have a very good backup before doing this. Also, strongly consider enabling `innodb_file_per_table` while you have mysql stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I have this approach.

1. Change name table to tmp:

   ```
   rename table pppoe_auth_users to pppoe_auth_users_tmp;
   ```
2. Disable keys:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE pppoe_auth_users_tmp DISABLE KEYS;
   ```
3. Recreate table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `pppoe_auth_users` (
     `host` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
     `username` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
     `vlan` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `ipaddr` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
     `interface` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
     `qos_in_enable` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `qos_out_enable` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
     `bw_in` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `bw_out` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `uptime` int(20) DEFAULT '0',
     `clock` int(20) DEFAULT '0',
     KEY `t1` (`host`,`clock`,`ipaddr`),
     KEY `t2` (`host`,`clock`,`username`),
     KEY `auth_users` (`clock`) USING BTREE
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs;*
   ```
4. Disable keys:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE pppoe_auth_users DISABLE KEYS;
   ```
5. Insert data with time slice needed in this case last 60 days:

   ```
   insert into pppoe_auth_users (select * from pppoe_auth_users_tmp where clock>=(unix_timestamp()-(86400*60)));
   ```
6. Enable keys:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE pppoe_auth_users ENABLE KEYS;
   ```
7. Drop if needed old data:

   ```
   drop table pppoe_auth_users_tmp;
   ```